# connecting android to tcp-ip for data transfer

Tags: android, networking, tcpclient, tcp, lwip

Is there a good solution for connecting an Android device to tcp/ip? Solutions I've found so far include the following: rooting the phone, actual Internet connection, widgets or existing apps. I can't do any of those things.

I'm trying to receive data over a serial port into an android app without a third party connection, without rooting the device. I'm willing to admit tcp/ip might not be the best answer, but I do need things like packets and ack.

I'm looking at implementing application level lightweight ip (LWIP), but the breakdown is: not seeing a good software solution to get the information from the stack at the other end. Thoughts?